# Como detectar logout quando o navegador fecha ou quando a sessão encerra(tempo limite atingido, inatividade etc) no laravel 8?

Tags: php, laravel, session, framework, laravel-8

Estou tentando mudando o comportamento padrão da classe Illuminate\Session\CookieSessionHandler para que quando o método destroy seja invocado seja registrado na base de dados quando uma sessão do usuário foi encerrada. Como essa classe se encontra no diretório vendor e este é reescrito para cada atualização do framework, decidi criar uma nova classe e estender a que quero modificar, para isso sobrescrevi o método destroy, além disso também criei um Provider de forma similar ao indicado na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#adding-custom-session-drivers), contudo não tive o resultado esperado, alguém poderia me falar se tem uma maneira mais fácil de registrar quando a sessão do usuário acaba por inatividade ou ter fechado o browser?. Seguem os arquivos modificados no processo, desde já muito obrigado:

### Classe Provider

```
class CookieSessionProvider extends SessionServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The container instance.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container
     */
    protected $container;
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Session::extend('customCookie', function ($app) {
            // Return an implementation of SessionHandlerInterface...
            return new CustomCookieSessionHandler($this->app->make('cookie'), config('session.lifetime'));
        });
    }
}
```

---

### Classe Handler

```
<?php


namespace SIICA\Extensions;

    
class CustomCookieSessionHandler extends CookieSessionHandler
{
    public function destroy($sessionId)
    {
        event(new UserLogoutEvent(Auth::user()));
        return parent::destroy($sessionId);
    }
}
```

### Alteração no .env

```
SESSION_DRIVER=customCookie
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
```

### Alterações no config/session.php

```
  'customCookie' => env(
        'SESSION_COOKIE',
        Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_session'
    ),
```

### Alterações no config/app.php

```
'providers' => [
 //Outros providers omitidos
 SIICA\Providers\Custom\CookieSessionProvider::class,
    ],
```

### Manipulação do evento do logout

```
class UserLogoutListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param  object  $event
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle(UserLogoutEvent $event)
    {
        $logoutDateTime = new \DateTime();
        $userAccess = UserAccess::where('user_id', $event->user->id)
            ->whereNull('logout_at')->first();
        if (!empty($userAccess)){
            $userAccess->logout_at = $logoutDateTime->format(MYSQL_FORMAT_DATETIME);
            $userAccess->save();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Não tem como interceptar este fechamento do navegador, você poderia criar um command q teste os usuários q foram marcados no banco como autenticados e o registro de logout está nulo se existe uma entrada de cache de usuário autenticado, e agendar p executar a cada minuto. Para criar o cache, no login do usuário, gravar a informação de login no banco, e ainda um Cache com o id do usuário e o tempo de de expiração de cache a cada request.  Avisa se precisar de código p isso q eu posto mais tarde nas respostas

Comment: Obrigado amigo, caso possa contribuir com um exemplo de código agradeço.